# E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a tabbed activity with 4 fragments ,in fourth fragement(setting fragment )I want to display a  recycler view menu ,when I run my project I ,the recycler view menu is very slow and got E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
,I have searched about the solution but nothing work for me .

Logs

```
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode 
(without mOwningView)
D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 
0) or=1
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@5f44d70 
time:10538964
V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{98c56e4 
token=android.os.BinderProxy@6559f5e 
{com.example.zodiac.sawa/com.example.zodiac.sawa.MainActivity}} show : false
```

Here is my adapter (SettingAdapter.java):

```
 package com.example.zodiac.sawa.RecyclerViewAdapters;

 import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.SeekBar;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 import com.example.zodiac.sawa.R;
 import com.example.zodiac.sawa.models.SettingsRecyclerViewDataProvider;

 import org.w3c.dom.Text;

 import java.util.ArrayList;


 public class SettingsAdapter extends 
 RecyclerView.Adapter<SettingsAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {
 ArrayList<SettingsRecyclerViewDataProvider> 
 settingsRecyclerViewDataProviders = new 
 ArrayList<SettingsRecyclerViewDataProvider>();
 View view;

public SettingsAdapter(ArrayList<SettingsRecyclerViewDataProvider> settingsRecyclerViewDataProviders) {
    this.settingsRecyclerViewDataProviders = settingsRecyclerViewDataProviders;
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.settings_item_view, parent, false);
    RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
    return recyclerViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
    SettingsRecyclerViewDataProvider dataProvider = settingsRecyclerViewDataProviders.get(position);
    holder.image.setImageResource(dataProvider.getImage());
    holder.text.setText(dataProvider.getText());


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return settingsRecyclerViewDataProviders.size();
}

public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView image;
    ;
    TextView text;

    public RecyclerViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);


    }
}
}
```

And here the fragment code

package com.example.zodiac.sawa.MainTabs;

/**
 * Created by zodiac on 03/27/2017.
 */

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.zodiac.sawa.R;
import com.example.zodiac.sawa.RecyclerViewAdapters.SettingsAdapter;
import com.example.zodiac.sawa.models.SettingsRecyclerViewDataProvider;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Setting extends Fragment {
  View view;
  RecyclerView recyclerView;
  SettingsAdapter recyclerAdapter;
  RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
  int image1=R.drawable.image1;
  int image2=R.drawable.image2;
  int image3=R.drawable.image1;
ArrayList<SettingsRecyclerViewDataProvider>dataProviders=newArrayList<SettingsRecyclerViewDataProvider>();
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view=  inflater.inflate(R.layout.setting_tab,container,false);
    recyclerView=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    SettingsRecyclerViewDataProvider settingsRecyclerViewDataProvider=new SettingsRecyclerViewDataProvider(image1,"Your name");
    dataProviders.add(settingsRecyclerViewDataProvider);
    dataProviders.add(settingsRecyclerViewDataProvider);
    dataProviders.add(settingsRecyclerViewDataProvider);

    recyclerAdapter=new SettingsAdapter(dataProviders);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);

    return view;
}
}
```

And here is my settingsRecyclerViewDataProviders.java class

```
package com.example.zodiac.sawa.models;



public class SettingsRecyclerViewDataProvider {
int image;
String text;
public SettingsRecyclerViewDataProvider(int image,String text){
    this.image=image;
    this.text=text;
}

public void setImage(int image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public int getImage() {
    return image;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
 }
}
```

Comment: In general I don't really see anything wrong with your code (that could slow it down, that is). Could the SettingsRecyclerViewDataProvider be doing something that's slowing down your code? Could you post the code?
P.S. you should never save the view you create in onCreateViewHolder to a field.

Comment: Please show the full logcat

Comment: Thanks for your reply, In have posted SettingsRecyclerViewDataProvider  ,hope that you can help me .

Comment: "No adapter attached; skipping layout"  this error occurs generally when adapter is empty. I think your SettingRecyclerViewDataProvider class is providing data after recyler view set adapter is called. Please set a empty adapter first then when data is available then call notifyDataSetChange.

Comment: can you please post the code

Comment: @Chandan I sent an empty arraylist then added the data and notifyDataSetChanged(); ,but that doesn't work for me

Comment: @cricket_007 I have posted the logs above .

Comment: Are you sure it is your app that is generating that message?

Comment: And you should be using a `PreferenceFragment` anyway for settings

Comment: @cricket_007 yes that message from my app since it appears when I open my fragment .But what is the relation between the PreferenceFragment  and this error?

Comment: You said in the question that you are trying to use a RecyclerView "for settings". My point was that you shouldn't need one

Comment: @cricket_007 I mean that the fragment called setting ,but not only for settings